# Discord: Interaction has already been acknowledged

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a panel with buttons, if I click a single button and then another, an error is shown:

```
DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged.
    at handleErrors (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Discord Bot Version 1.0.0 (Beta)\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:640:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async BurstHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Discord Bot Version 1.0.0 (Beta)\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:736:23)
    at async REST.request (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Discord Bot Version 1.0.0 (Beta)\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1387:22)
    at async ButtonInteraction.deferUpdate (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Discord Bot Version 1.0.0 (Beta)\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:200:5)
    at async InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Discord Bot Version 1.0.0 (Beta)\buttons\moderates\listRaiting.js:48:9) {
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: { type: 6 } },
  rawError: {
    message: 'Interaction has already been acknowledged.',
    code: 40060
  },
  code: 40060,
  status: 400,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1107914467368521809/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTEwNzkxNDQ2NzM2ODUyMTgwOTo0S2p0RTFmRkRKcE8xZTR2YnRvT1U2WnRSSmluS21qTjlEWUxoQ05INFZrWUFBNTV2aXhnRjRIYWV2WVhmUUNJMHZlWVQwenNBdDBEY1pRWHUzS3Z4UEM5dXB0NWVPbm1mdlVRTlBHR1RxYmJpV3hvOWV2czFRMndsU25WWFRkUQ/callback'
}
```

My code:

````js
const {
  ActionRowBuilder,
  ButtonBuilder,
  EmbedBuilder,
  ButtonStyle,
} = require('discord.js');

async function listRatingButton(interaction, roleId = '1060382379723731097') {
  const guild = interaction.guild;
  const role = await guild.roles.fetch(roleId);

  if (!role) {
    return interaction.reply(
      'Не удалось найти роль. Пожалуйста, проверьте ID роли.',
    );
  }

  const membersWithRole = guild.members.cache.filter((member) =>
    member.roles.cache.has(roleId),
  );
  const membersArray = Array.from(membersWithRole.values());

  const pages = [];
  const membersPerPage = 15;

  for (let i = 0; i < membersArray.length; i += membersPerPage) {
    pages.push(membersArray.slice(i, i + membersPerPage));
  }

  const row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
    new ButtonBuilder()
      .setCustomId('previous')
      .setEmoji(':previous:1102791113988898837')
      .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),
    new ButtonBuilder()
      .setCustomId('next')
      .setEmoji(':next:1102791111774306365')
      .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),
  );

  await interaction.reply({
    embeds: [getEmbed(pages[0], role.name, 0, membersPerPage)],
    components: [row],
  });

  const filter = (i) => i.user.id === interaction.user.id;
  const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
    filter,
    time: 60000,
  });

  let currentPage = 0;
  collector.on('collect', async (i) => {
    try {
      if (i.customId === 'previous' && currentPage !== 0) {
        currentPage--;
      } else if (i.customId === 'next' && currentPage < pages.length - 1) {
        currentPage++;
      }
      if (!i.deferred && !i.replied) {
        await i.deferUpdate();
        await i.editReply({
          embeds: [
            getEmbed(
              pages[currentPage],
              role.name,
              currentPage,
              membersPerPage,
            ),
          ],
          components: [row],
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  });
}

function getEmbed(page, roleName, pageNumber, membersPerPage) {
  let memberList = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < page.length; i++) {
    memberList += `${pageNumber * membersPerPage + i + 1}. ${
      page[i].user.tag
    }\n`;
  }

  const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle(`Участники с ролью ${roleName}`)
    .setDescription('```fix\n' + memberList + '```')
    .setColor('#0099ff');

  return embed;
}

module.exports = { execute: listRatingButton };
````